# Was Delphi (and her plot twist) foreshadowed in previous Harry Potter books?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, foreshadowing

I have finally just got to reading *Cursed Child*. It was revealed that Delphini, or Delphi, is the daughter of Voldemort and Bellatrix. Was this ever implied in the books? Wouldn't there have been something?

I actually spent the greater part of the week trying to figure out if J.K. Rowling implied this anywhere in her writing; I can't find anything. Voldemort Day, it seems, was very loosely referenced in book 1 (Ron says he thinks that there would be a whole day around Voldemort if he won); as ridiculous as it seems, it was referenced.

Anyhow, was Delphi's plot twist of being Voldemort's daughter planned out from the beginning? If so, where can I find it in the books?

Comment: other than Bellatrix's fawning over the Dark Lord....not in the slightest. It's little more than fan fiction with Rowling's imprimatur

Comment: Hardly. There's absolutely no hint at the Dark Lord having a daughter, or even getting involved in a sexual relationship. Romantic relationships are out of the picture, obviously. In any case, The Cursed Child is fanfiction at best. And a very bad one.

Comment: The play wasn't even her idea, so it would be hard for her to have foreshadowed it years before it was even pitched for her.

Comment: Seems like JK made a coding reference there. Every programmer knows that Delphi is a spawn of evil.

Comment: This is impossible to answer (well) -- a "no" answer would require an exhaustive inclusion of all seven novels to prove something doesn't exist, and it doesn't appear that a "yes" can be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is foreshadowed.

It is explicitly said, in book 7, that Bellatrix talks to Voldemort "as a lover". Also, he is suspiciously furious when she dies.

The possibility of Bellatrix having a child is briefly evoked in book 6. When Narcissa is worried about Draco's mission and asks Snape to help him, Bellatrix says she should be proud that Draco was chosen and adds that, if she had sons, she would want them to be Voldemort's servants.

Bellatrix was probably already pregnant at this time and was thinking about her child's future. (The child turned out to be a girl but, of course, Bellatrix could not know this yet.)

The fact that Bellatrix does not appear again in book 6 gives her time to carry her pregnancy to term and give birth.

Comment: This answer would be improved by quotes from the relevant parts of books 6 and 7

Comment: Bellatrix being pregnant in Book 6 is wild speculation at best.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think J.K Rowling foreshadowed this in the books, no foreshadowings in any of the 7 books I'd say.

Comment: This is an unsupported statement of opinion.

Comment: There's a lot of foreshadowing in the books that hint to future events in the main series.

Comment: @ZeissIkon how would you provide support for a negative answer? Contradictory info maybe, but if there's just nothing in there either way...

Comment: I was referring to the single sentence "answer" starting with "I don't think" -- which is the answerer calling it opinion, and then not typing even a second sentence to support.